# EJS Inline DOM Selector Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, charts, ejs, chart.js2

I'm using Node.js, Express, Chart.js and EJS for templates. I want a template that gets passed a variable with a list of objects. Each object defines a chart for Chart.js to render in the webpage.

Chart.js requires that you store the canvas from the DOM in a variable which you pass as an argument to the `new Chart()` but in the code below, my EJS references `document` which gets an error saying it's undefined at the time of referencing it. How can I get around this?

```html
<div class='report-content'>
    <!-- 'reportSheet' is a variable passed in from the Express route definition. -->
    <!-- for each chart object in the list of charts... -->
    <% reportSheet.forEach(function(chart){ %>
        <!-- create area for that chart -->
        <div class="chart-region">
            <div class="chart-item">
                <h3>Chart Title</h3>
                <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
                <% var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart"); %>
                <% var myChart = new Chart(ctx, chart); %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

Here's the example way to build a chart according to the Chart.js docs:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
</script>
```

For some context: the point is for users to be able to view the webpage and add new charts like a dashboard, so the database needs to store a list of every chart they make for the dashboard.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Let me tell you something....ejs is templating engine and runs on back end....you cannot take reference to document on backend... What you can do is print JavaScript using ejs which will run on the client....or make an ajax call to server to get data and make the chart using chartjs

Comment: Thanks for your advice Tolsee. It helped me realise I needed AJAX. I'm quite new to web dev. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY! Finally figured it out after much headache. My novice skill level is about to be apparent.

So the sequence of events goes as such:

1. Visit address in browser
2. Nodejs/Express server responds with my EJS template with no charts
3. That EJS template runs an AJAX script
4. AJAX script contacts server to query MongoDB for my chart data
5. Server retrieves chart data from MongoDB and sends it back to AJAX script in JSON format
6. AJAX script receives chart data and uses $ string literal formatting to inject necessary HTML and new script code into the page loaded on step 1

**Here's the relevant code**

Page loads with no charts. Footer of my page calls AJAX script:

```
        </div>
        <script src="../../public/ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

AJAX script gets chart data from server and injects it into page:

```
$.get("/charts", function(data){   // contacts the server route shown in code block below
    data = data[1];    // only using first chart in array of charts for now
    var chartData = JSON.stringify(data.chart); // 'data.chart' contains nested objects that describe the chart, so it must be stringified (this caused me days of headache)
    // Now inject HTML back into original page with multi-line string literal formatting. Could also use regular string concatenation.
    $(".report-content").html(
    `
        <div class="chart-region">
            <div class="chart-item">
                <h3>${data.chartName}</h3>
                <canvas id="${data._id}" width='400' height='200'></canvas>
                // script to create a chart
                <script>
                    var ctx = $("#${data._id}");
                    var chartVar = new Chart(ctx, ${chartData});
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
    );
});
```

Server's **/charts** route looks like this:

```
app.get("/charts", function(req, res){
    Charts.find({}, function(err, chart){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(chart);
        }
    });
});
```

And that's it!

Right now I'm only injecting one chart but to load the whole array of charts you'd have to get rid of `data = data[1]` and run a loop something like the following (be aware I haven't tested this code yet):

```
$.get("/charts", function(data){    // data contains the entire array of chartContainers
    data.forEach(function(chartContainer){      // chartContainer contains a chart's data and metadata about it like a name
        var chartData = JSON.stringify(chartContainer.chart);   // chartContainer.chart contains the actual chart data that Chart.js needs
        $(".report-content").append(
        `
            <div class="chart-region">
                <div class="chart-item">
                    <h3>${chartContainer.chartName}</h3>
                    <canvas id="${chartContainer._id}" width='400' height='200'></canvas>
                    <script>
                        var ctx = $("#${chartContainer._id}");
                        var chartVar = new Chart(ctx, ${chartData});
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        `
        );
    });
});
```